# How to do selection sorting in Java?

Tags: java, sorting, selection-sort

Here is the my code for a project I am working on for class:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Array;

public class Project10_MaryEvans {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] numbers = {2, 7, 5, 3, 4, 9, 8, 10, 1, 6};
        int i = 0;
        final int NUMBERS_SIZE = 10;
        System.out.print("Unsorted: ");
        for (i = 0; i < NUMBERS_SIZE; ++i){
            System.out.print(numbers[i] + " ");{
                System.out.println();
            }
            sorting(numbers, NUMBERS_SIZE);
            System.out.print("Sorted: ");
            for(i = 0; i < NUMBERS_SIZE; ++i){
                System.out.print(numbers[i] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
            return;
        }
    }
    public static int[] shuffle(int[] numbers){
        for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; ++i) {
            numbers[i] = (int)Math.random() * numbers[i];
        }
        return numbers;
    }
    public static void sorting(int[] numbers, int numberSize) {
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        int indexSmallest = 0;
        int temp = 0;

        for (i = 0; i < numberSize; ++i) {
            indexSmallest = i;
            for(j = i + 1; j < numberSize; ++j) {
                if(numbers[j] < numbers[indexSmallest]) {
                    indexSmallest = j;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am not getting the correct output. My output is:

```
Unsorted: 2  
Sorted: 2 7 5 3 4 9 8 10 1 6
```

Comment: I would have thought that your code should do 1) for loop 2) sorting 3) for loop, but you seem to have embedded steps 2 and 3 into your first for loop

Comment: Time to learn to use a debugger it appears.

Comment: The block structure in your main method is rather messed up.  That is one reason you are getting the wrong output.  You are also "reusing" a loop variable in a nested loop ... though I think the nesting is actually mistaken.  Hint: look at the code .... carefully.

Answer (score 0):

I'm juste gonna give you tips here:

- Use `Arrays.toString(numbers)` to print your array easily.
- Use `numbers.length` to get the size of the `numbers` array.
- (the most important one) Your sorting doesn't actually do any sorting, you just set indexes values, but you don't modify the array `numbers` (`numbers[i] = numbers[j]` for example).
- Your first loop (in main) is useless.

And read the comments.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you have make two for loop nested in your main function, it should be like

```
    System.out.print("Unsorted: ");
    for (i = 0; i < NUMBERS_SIZE; ++i){
        System.out.print(numbers[i] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();

    sorting(numbers, NUMBERS_SIZE);

    System.out.print("Sorted: ");
    for(i = 0; i < NUMBERS_SIZE; ++i){
        System.out.print(numbers[i] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
    return;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `sorting` function you're forgetting to exchange current element with the minimal found. You're just computing indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Use this method for sorting. Not need int numberSize parameter. It can get through array length. If you need int numberSize parameter replace numbers.length with numberSize.

```
   public static void sorting(int[] numbers) {
     int temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < numbers.length; j++) {                 
            if (numbers[i] > numbers[j]) {
                temp = numbers[i];
                numbers[i] = numbers[j];
                numbers[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Main Method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] numbers = {2, 7, 5, 3, 4, 9, 8, 10, 1, 6};
    int i = 0;
    final int NUMBERS_SIZE = 10;
    System.out.print("Unsorted: ");
    for (i = 0; i < NUMBERS_SIZE; ++i){
        System.out.print(numbers[i] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
    sorting(numbers);
    System.out.print("Sorted: ");
    for(i = 0; i < NUMBERS_SIZE; ++i){
        System.out.print(numbers[i] + " ");
    }
}
```